# Dart: how to return value from calling a recursive function?

Tags: dart

How do I return the value from a recursive function?

I know how to pass a value to a function and return a value:

```java
void main(){

  Halfer(myNumber) {
    myNumber = myNumber~/2;
    return myNumber;
  };
  
  var myNumber = 99;
  print(Halfer(myNumber));
}
```

That prints `49` to the console.

The following code prints a single digit value to the console:

```java
void main(){

  SingleDigitizer(myNumber) {
    if (myNumber > 9) {
      myNumber = myNumber~/10;
      SingleDigitizer(myNumber);
    } else {
      print(myNumber);
    }
  };
  
  var myNumber = 99;
  SingleDigitizer(myNumber);
}
```

The result `9` prints to the console.

The next program doesn't work. It prints `null` to the console:

```java
void main(){

  SingleDigitizer(myNumber) {
    if (myNumber > 9) {
      myNumber = myNumber~/10;
      SingleDigitizer(myNumber);
    } else {
      return myNumber;
    }
  };
  
  var myNumber = 99;
  print(SingleDigitizer(myNumber));
}
```

How do I return the value from a recursive function?

Comment: You return the same way you do for any function, recursive or otherwise: you use the `return` statement.  Your `SingleDigitzer` function fails to return a value along all code paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods:

1. Return from internal calling function

```dart
void main(){

  SingleDigitizer(myNumber) {
    if (myNumber > 9) {
      myNumber = myNumber~/10;
      return SingleDigitizer(myNumber);
    } else {
      return myNumber;
    }
  };
  
  var myNumber = 99;
  print(SingleDigitizer(myNumber));
}
```

Notice the `return` in line 6.

2. Set up variable to assign the value

```dart
void main(){
  var result;

  SingleDigitizer(myNumber) {
    if (myNumber > 9) {
      myNumber = myNumber~/10;
      SingleDigitizer(myNumber);
    } else {
      result = myNumber;
    }
  };

  SingleDigitizer(99);
  print(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to define some types, at least the return type of the `SingleDigitizer` method (which should also be written in lower case).

If you tell the compiler that `SingleDigitizer` returns an `int`, it will help you to find your mistake ;-)

Hint: The `if` block has no `return` statement, the `else` block does.

Answer (score -1):

This code works but I don't understand it:

```java
void main(){

  singleDigitizer(myNumber) {
    if (myNumber > 9) {
      myNumber = myNumber~/10;
      return singleDigitizer(myNumber);
    } else {
      return myNumber;
    }
  };
  
  int myNumber = 5555;
  print(singleDigitizer(myNumber));
}
```

My original code was:

1. If the number is greater than 9, divide it by ten.
2. Do #1 again until the number is 9 or less.
3. If the number is 9 or less, return it.

It should never get stuck in #1. Eventually it should go to #3 and return the result.

I don't understand why putting `return` in #1 fixed the problem.

This returns `null`:

```java
void main() {
  tenDivider3(myNumber3) {
    myNumber3 = myNumber3 ~/ 10;
    print(myNumber3);
    return (myNumber3);
  }

  tenDivider2(myNumber2) {
    myNumber2 = myNumber2 ~/ 10;
    print(myNumber2);
    tenDivider3(myNumber2);
  }

  tenDivider1(myNumber1) {
    myNumber1 = myNumber1 ~/ 10;
    print(myNumber1);
    tenDivider2(myNumber1);
  }

  int myNumber = 5555;
  print(tenDivider1(myNumber));
}
```

The result:

```
555
55
5
null
```

This returns the result correctly:

```java
void main() {
  tenDivider3(myNumber3) {
    myNumber3 = myNumber3 ~/ 10;
    print(myNumber3);
    return (myNumber3);
  }

  tenDivider2(myNumber2) {
    myNumber2 = myNumber2 ~/ 10;
    print(myNumber2);
    return tenDivider3(myNumber2);
  }

  tenDivider1(myNumber1) {
    myNumber1 = myNumber1 ~/ 10;
    print(myNumber1);
    return tenDivider2(myNumber1);
  }

  int myNumber = 5555;
  print(tenDivider1(myNumber));
}
```

The result:

```
555
55
5
5
```

In both programs `myNumber3` prints as `5`. One program returns `5`, the other returns `null`. I don't understand why the same value is returned as different values in different programs.

Comment: In your original code without a `return` statement, your code *does* keep dividing by 10 and then eventually return the result.  *However*, the returned result is *not* returned to the original caller.  It's returned *only* to the caller of the last recursive call.  Without a `return` statement for all code paths, you're doing the equivalent of `f(g(x))` where `g` returns a value but `f` returns nothing.  It might help you if you ran through your code with a very simple example that iterates only once.

Comment: Using your first `tenDivider1` example: `tenDivider1` does not return any value.  The caller will get back `null`.  It does not matter what work `tenDivider1` does or what other functions it calls.  It returns nothing to the caller.  Unlike some languages, Dart functions do not implicitly return the result of the last statement or expression.

Comment: OK, Betty calls Bob to ask what time the party starts. Bob calls Sue to ask when the party starts. Sue calls Ted and Ted tells her when the party starts. But Sue doesn't call Bob and Bob doesn't call Betty so Betty never learns when the party starts.